# Using Angular Material, do I need to systematically import my SASS module where my theme is declared?

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material

I'm using Angular material v15.2.9.

I just noticed by accident that when I import the module where my theme is declared, Material is behaving differently. For example I noticed that the height of mat-row (inside a mat-table) is now set to 52px (https://material.angular.io/guide/mdc-migration#table). It looks like more css rules are now loaded when I import my styles module directly in my component, using @use '_styles'; in .scss sheet.

This is how _styles.scss module looks :

```
    // see https://material.angular.io/guide/theming
    
    @use '@angular/material' as mat;
    @use '_core-styles' as core;
    
    @include mat.core();
    
    $my-primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$pink-palette, 700);
    $my-accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$amber-palette, A200, A100, A400);
    $my-warn: mat.define-palette(mat.$red-palette);
    
    $my-theme: mat.define-light-theme((
     color: (
       primary: $my-primary,
       accent: $my-accent,
       warn: $my-warn,
     ),
     typography: mat.define-typography-config(),
     density: 0,
    ));
    
    // Emit theme-dependent styles for common features used across multiple components.
        @include mat.core-theme($my-theme);
    
    // Include the theme mixins for other components you use here.
    @include mat.all-component-themes($my-theme);
    
    // be able to use material typography
    $my-typography: mat.get-typography-config($my-theme);
    @include mat.typography-hierarchy($my-typography);
    
    // include it in core library
    @include core.mylibtheme($my-theme);
    
    body {
      margin: 0px;
    }
    
    html, body {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
    }
    
    .dense-1 {
      @include mat.all-component-densities(-1);
    }    
    
    .dense-2 {
      @include mat.all-component-densities(-2);
    }
    
    .dense-3 {
      @include mat.all-component-densities(-3);
    }
    
    .no-select {
      user-select: none;
    }
    
    .clickable {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
```

Have I missed something here ?

My styles modules is included as follow in 'build' architect of angular.json :

```
    architect.build.options.styles =
    \[
    "src/assets/styles/\_styles.scss",
    "node_modules/core/src/\_core-styles.scss"
    \]
```

I guess my main question are :

- Why the rule of 52px height for mat-row hasn't been loaded previously since _styles.scss is declared as global sheet ?

I tried to investigate the origin of the rule of 52px in Chrome DevTools but no luck..